# Django filter objects based on the value of a field of the last data in another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filters

There are 2 models

`class A(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()`

`class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)`

Now I want to filter objects of class A based on the last data in class B status.

if there are 2 datas of Model B

`id | a   | status
  1 | a   |  True
  2 | abc |  False
  3 | a   |  False
  4 | abc |  True`

So if I want to filter objects of Model A which are having status False.
In this case it will give me

`a`.

If I wanted to filter objects of Model A which are having status True.
In this case it should return me 
`abc`.

I want to write a query something like

`A.objects.filter(b__status__last=True)`

Is it possible to do using filters?

Comment: Seems like both rows with `False` and `True` status contains `abc` in your table.
Please confirm do you need to get name of class A that is in the last created Class B instance that has `True` or `False` status? Didn't get what you want to get as result? Queryset or class A value?

Comment: I want all the Class A datas whose last data status in  Class B is True.

Comment: I have updated the question. Check it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use annotate effectively here.

```
A.objects.annotate(latest_b=Max("b__created_at")).filter(b__status=True).latest('latest_b')
```

Here, we're annotating each object of `A` to have a `latest_by` field and then fetching the latest object after filtering by the status of b. This should work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
from django.db.models import Max, F

A.objects.annotate(latest=Max('b__id')).filter(b__id=F('latest'),b__status=True)
```

Comment: Nice solution, only use `True` instead of `'True'` ;-)